# Adding a Question Mark in Page Number in the Table in SQL Reporting Service

Tags: reporting-services

I have created a report in sql reporting service and used a table. If the total page is bigger than 1 then it shows like 1 from 2?.  When i passed to second page then it displays 2 from 3?

My question is that why it adds question mark end of the next page number? My customer is not happy with that. How I can fix it?
It is also weird because the second number must show total page number but it also changes

PS: I use sql server 2008 r2

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Put a header or footer on your report.  Add a textbox.  Set the textbox value to the Built-in field for OverallPageNumber.

```
=Globals!OverallTotalPages
```

This will force SSRS to calculate the total number of pages in the report instead of just using its default "on demand" processing of one page at a time.

You can then set that text box visibility property to hidden if you don't want to actually show it on the report, or set it to something like

```
="Page " & Globals!OverallPageNumber & " of " & Globals!OverallTotalPages
```

[image]